# Geckodriver Selenium/Java not working on macOS Big Sur

Tags: geckodriver

I am using Selenium with Java and when i try to launch the Firefox browser using Geckodriver it says "“geckodriver” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software."

I've tried with spctl --add --label 'Approved'  but it didn't work.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Check https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases the section "known problems"

Answer (score 10):

Open "System Settings > Security & Privacy" immediately after trying to execute Gecko Driver, just after you receive the system pop-up claiming it is from an unidentified developer. The last program to be flagged for security issues should be available here (in this case, Gecko Driver).[image]

Click on "Allow Anyway" and execute the program again. The security pop-up should appear again, this time with an "OK" button. Click on it and the driver should run.